# Import Multiple Excel Files

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created the following to import 47 excel files into Access; all with the same naming convention REPORT01, REPORT02 etc.

However, I now have a list of files with varying names.  Can someone suggest how I would tailor this to accomdate the change?  I was thinking that I could create a separate module with the excel file names in that the main code just references whilst it loops through the folder.  If it finds a match, import.

```
Sub ImportTables()
' Define base path
Const cstrFolder As String = "F:\TCB_HR_KPI\Data View\"

Dim strExt As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim i As Long
Dim fileCount As Long

' Check all 47 files exist
For i = 1 To 47
    strFile = cstrFolder & "REPORT" & Right("0" & i, 2) & ".xls"
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then fileCount = fileCount + 1
Next i

' Partial results allowed, only exit when no matches found
If fileCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Files not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Second loop to import data
fileCount = 0
For i = 1 To 47
    strFile = cstrFolder & "REPORT" & Right("0" & i, 2) & ".xls"
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "Found: " & strFile
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "REPORT" & Right("0" & i, 2), strFile, True
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
    End If
Next i

MsgBox fileCount & " files imported."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding is always a disaster waiting to happen.  I would suggest making this table-based.  Fill a table with your report names (that is, assuming you know exactly what they are), and open a recordset of that table.  Then you can loop through the table and call your Import function with that filename.

You can probably just put an

```
On Error Resume
```

statement in your code, so that if the file name doesn't exist it will simply move to the next one.  Or you can do something a little more intricate where it searches the actual folder.  I don't have time to modify this, but the code I use looks like this:

```
Dim fsoSysObj      As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim z
Dim fdrFolder      As Scripting.Folder
Dim fdrSubFolder   As Scripting.Folder
Dim filFile        As Scripting.File
'Dim strSQL As String

' Return new FileSystemObject.
Set fsoSysObj = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

' Get folder.
Set fdrFolder = fsoSysObj.GetFolder(strPath)

' Loop through Files collection
For Each filFile In fdrFolder.Files
```

You would just have to do a dLookup in your filename table against filFile.Name to see if it exists.